# Pentaho Kettle: Transforming two Unix datetime columns into one

Tags: json, unix, amazon-redshift, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to use Pentaho Kettle to read the Json file with the structure below and insert the data into the DW (Redshift).

```
{
  "_id": {
    "_data": "11111111111111"
  },
  "operationType": "insert",
  "clusterTime": {
    "$timestamp": {
      "t": 1599495064,
      "i": 1
    }
  },
  "ns": {
    "db": "abc",
    "coll": "abc"
  },
  "documentKey": {
    "_id": {
      "$uuid": "abcabcabcabcabcabc"
    }
  },
  "fullDocument": {
    "_id": {
      "$uuid": "abcabcabcabcabcabc"
    },
    "orderNumber": "1234567",
    "externalOrderId": "12345678",
    "orderDateTime": "2020-09-11T08:06:26Z[UTC]",
    "attraction": "abc",
    "entryDate": {
      "$date": 1599523200000
    },
    "entryTime": {
      "$date": 1599472800000
    },
    "requestId": "abc",
    "ticketUrl": "abc",
    "tickets": [
      {
        "passId": "1111111",
        "externalTicketId": "1234567"
      },
      {
        "passId": "222222222",
        "externalTicketId": "122442492"
      }
    ],
    "_class": "abc"
  }
}
```

As we see above both columns "entry_date" and "entry_time" are in Unix format. I need to somehow take the date component from "entry_date" and the time component from "entry_time" and transform both into a concatenated unique field that will give me the following output: "GMT: Monday, September 7, 2020 4:11:04 PM".

Also I would like to achieve the same for the field  "orderDateTime" - is there any way I could use Pentaho to transform that into the same format as the above "GMT: Monday, September 7, 2020 4:11:04 PM"?

Below you can see how the 3 fields above ("entry_time", "entry_date" and "orderDatetime") are currently set up for the "Select Values" step. From there I would then take the data into the DW with the Table Output step as seen in the illustration below. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: use modified java-script and convert unixtime stamp in the regular date format, then use concate this two values.